# Preimage of a dense set under continuous onto function

Tags: general-topology

I know preimage of a dense set under open map is dense.  Is it true that preimage of a dense set under continuous onto function is dense?

Actually when I did the problem that continuous onto image of a dense set is dense.  Suddenly I thought that question.  Is that true?  If so,  then how to prove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true. Consider the identity map $\operatorname{id}\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where the first $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the discrete topology and the second, the euclidean topology. This map is continuous and surjective.

$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ under the Euclidean topology. Its inverse image under $\operatorname{id}$ is also $\mathbb{Q}$. But $\mathbb{Q}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$ under the discrete topology.

EDIT: OP asked the following: If we allow both $X$ and $Y$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual Euclidean topology. Will the hypothesis be true? The answer is no.

Consider the function: $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ by setting $f(x) =0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=x$ if $x\ge 0$. This map is continuous and surjective. The set $D=(0,\infty)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. But its preimage under $f$, which is still $(0,\infty)$, is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$! A huge reason is because the map $f$ is not open.

Comment: Wow Great, thanks

Comment: is it true for real analysis i. e,  if we take domain and codomain are $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology then result is true?

Comment: Hi @Siraj I have edited my answer to include one more counter example.

Comment: Note: You accidentally defined your second counterexample as the zero function; you'll probably want $f(x) = x$ if $x \geq 0$. I cannot edit this change into the post however since it would want me to change more than six characters for an edit.

Answer (score 0):

False.

*Brief/Nutshell argument:*  False because then the pre-image of any non-empty proper subset would be dense in the discrete topology; which it can't.

*Full argument:*  Cosider this counterargument:

- Let $\{\emptyset,X\}=\tau_1\subset \tau_2=2^X$ be the indiscrete and the discrete topologies on a set $X$ with at-least 2 points.
- The closure of any non-empty subset $Y$ of $(X,\tau_1)$ must be equal to all of $X$ itself (since the only $\tau_1$-closed set containting $Y$ must be $X$).  In particular, the $\tau_1$-closure $cl_{\tau_1}(\{x\})$ of any point $x\in X$ must be equal to all of $X$.  That is, $\{x\}$ is dense in $(X,\tau_1)$.
- Since the complement of $x$ is $X-\{x\}\in 2^X$, then the $\tau_2$-closure of $\{x\}$ in $X$ is itself $\{x\}$; which by assumption was not $X$ itself since the latter contained at-least two points.
- Every function $f:(X,\tau_2)\rightarrow (X,\tau_1)$ is [continuous][2] since then every
  $$
  U\in \tau_1  \Rightarrow f^{-1}[U] \in 2^X = \tau_2.
  $$
  In particular, the map $f(y)=y$ is continuous from $(X,\tau_2)$ to $(X,\tau_1)$.
- Now, consider the $\tau_1$-dense subset $\{x\}$ and note that
  $$
  cl_{\tau_2}\left(f^{-1}[\{x\}]\right)=cl_{\tau_2}\left(\{x\}\right)=\{x\}\neq X 
  \mbox{ but } cl_{\tau_1}\left(f^{-1}[\{x\}]\right)=X
  $$ 
  Therefore, 1 is false.

*Intuitive explanation:*  If 1 were true then basically any set would be dense since you could "transfer density" from arbitrarily coarse topologies to arbitrarily fine ones.